# Assign variable names to list of mcmc objects

Tags: r, coda, mcmc

Maybe someone here with more expirience with mcmc objects can help me out.

Problem: I have a list with 20+ mcmc objects stored. I need to assign variable names for each of the mcmc object.

I have another list with all the variables names for each mcmc stored (as columns in dataframes).

I can do this individually, using the "varnames" function from the coda package, like this:

Being "votes" my dataframe list and "posterior" my mcmc object list..

```
names <- votes[[1]]$legis # extracts the names variable for the first dataframe on the list.
varnames(posterior[[1]]) <- names # assings the extracted names as variable names fo the first mcmc object on the list.
```

However, rather than doing this one by one, I would like to do it all at once. I've tried the following code...

```
p2 <- lapply(posterior, function(x)varnames(posterior[[x]]) <- names)
```

But i get `Error in *tmp*[[x]] : Recursive indexing failed at level 2` . I've tried some variations of that line, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to properly index this, or how to do what I want to do at all.

I know its kind of an specific problem, but maybe someone here can give me a hint or something.

Thanks in advance for the help. Sorry I can't provide some data, but it's kinda difficult to get workable samples of this.

Regards,
Federico

Comment: `lapply(posterior, function(x) varnames(x) <- names)` should work, otherwise you are indexing `posterior` by `x` when x is already `posterior[[1]]` or posterior[[2]]`

Comment: or `lapply(posterior, setNames, names)`, I think.

Comment: Mnel, i´ve tried your approach but i get a dim error. Error in dimnames(x)[[2]] <- value : 
  "length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any lapply.

try `names(posterior) <- votes[[1]]$legis`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn´t work since all the mcmc objects have different lenghts. I need  match the names column of df.1 with the varible names of mcmc.1 (the lenghts of each pair matches).